# Regarding relative open sets.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm watching this lecture by Francis Su at HarveyMudd and I am having trouble understanding why the pink subset $P$ of $Y$ is not open relative to $X$. I think I understand that $P$ is open relative to $Y$ because "relative to" changes the universe of discourse to $Y$ from $X$ so every $p\in P$ has an $\epsilon$ neighborhood $N(p,\epsilon)$ that is contained in $Y$. However, the class later agreed that $P$ is not open relative to $X$. How could this be when everything in $Y$ is also in $X$?

Link to lecture(@1:02:07): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeVA74yivyg&list=PL04BA7A9EB907EDAF&index=11

A similar picture he has drawn since video quality is terrible:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neighborhood in $Y$ of $p\in Y$ is not necessarily a neighborhood in $X$ of $p\in Y$.

For example the set $[0,1)$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $[0,2]$ but it is not a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R$.

Actually there is no neighborhood $N$ of $0$ in $\mathbb R$ that satisfies $N\subseteq[0,2]$.

Comment: Ahhh! gotcha. Thank you very much drhab!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$P$ can be seen to be the intersection of an open set in $X$ (complete the half-disk into a full disk) with $Y$. Thus $P$ is open in $X$ by definition (See Munkres for example).

Comment: Do you mean an open set in $X$?

Comment: When the disc is "completed" yes. However, what I was asking is when the disc was still "incomplete". Thank you for your answer.